# Finding Gaussian Probabilities from predefined clusters

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, probability

I am given a set of defined clusters and vectors that belong in these clusters. I wish to find the gaussian probabilities for every point wrt to each defined cluster. What is the best way to find the density functions of my defined clusters or the gaussian mixture parameters for each cluster? The parameters of density functions are computed through em algorithm but I am given the clusters and points.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the clusters, just let the mean and variance of each density function be the mean and variance of the points in each cluster, and let the mixing weight be (number of points in cluster)/(total number of points).